# knockoutjs to render span tags in my string

Tags: knockout.js

I have a string in my view model that looks like this `'<span>test</span>'`

When I data-bind with knockoutjs like `<td data-bind="text: spanstring"></td>`

the page shows the raw html, but can I render the tag instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`html-binding`** is exactly for this use-case:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

```
<td data-bind="html: spanstring"></td>
```

Live-Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/80jbvj83/

---

As a personal note:
I use the `html-binding` very seldom these days, as it **goes *against* separating view from viewmodel**.
If you goal is to render the data within predefined html-snippets you might be looking for **`template-binding`**.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Live-Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ps6bn8vy/1/